# Can't load html file with LoadHTMLGlob in production build. It's working in development

Tags: html, go, templates

I'm using the Go Gin package in my rest-API service. To add some data I used HTML file to submit the form with data. In development, it's working, but in the production build server not working, if I commented 'LoadHTMLGlob' block server working again. I think 'LoadHTMLGlob' can't load HTML. Please help to solve this issue.

my main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "ct-merchant-api/Config"
    "ct-merchant-api/Routes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)
var err error

func main() {
    Config.DB, err = gorm.Open("mysql", Config.DbURL(Config.BuildDBConfig()))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Status:", err)
    }
    defer Config.DB.Close()

    r := Routes.SetupRouter()
    
    // Load HTML   
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    
    //running
    runningPort := Config.GetServerInfo()
    _ = r.Run(":" + runningPort.ServerPort)
}
```

Route file:

```
package Routes

import (
    "ct-merchant-api/Controllers/Referral"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    api := gin.Default()
    config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config.AllowAllOrigins = true
    config.AllowCredentials = true
    config.AddAllowHeaders("authorization")
    api.Use(cors.New(config))

    api.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Welcome to GO-rib Server")
    })

    api.GET("/referral/:merchantId", Referral.LeadForm)
    api.POST("/add-lead", Referral.LeadAdd)

    return api
}
```

Project Structure:

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
├── README.md
├── Routes
│   ── Routes.go
└── templates
|   ── lead-add-response.html
|   ── referral.html
```

For Deployment I Create a service `go-web-api.service` in `/lib/systemd/system`

In `go-web-api.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=goweb

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart={my_project_build_file_path}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Your HTML file is present in your production environment?

Comment: There is most likely incorrect path in your production env. Please provide more info on file structure and how are you starting app.

Comment: @medasx file structure added. please check

Comment: @PrakashP yes, HTML file present in my production env.

Comment: @MasudMorshed can you share the error message? Also see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548291/4408364 and https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/2444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `WorkingDirectory` to your system file

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/project //add this line
ExecStart={my_project_build_file_path}
```